# Yeoman generator using gulp and angular with express server

Tags: angularjs, express, gulp, yeoman

I am trying to set up a MEAN stack web app using yeoman with the generator-gulp-angular, which comes without express server.
I tried to add express, but I am having trouble with it, the index html in .tmp folder doesn't find any of the `bower_components` folder items.
Anyone have a working example of such setup ?

I added the express server loading file which contains:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(rootPath, '/.tmp/serve')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(rootPath, '/bower_components')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(rootPath, '/src')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/.tmp/serve/index.html');
});
```

Comment: I can't really understand your question since MEAN means (Monogo, EXPRESS, Angular, and Node).  So you are not using a MEAN stack.  If you are trying to build your own MEAN stack you should check out the mean stack http://mean.io/ all this work is already done for you.  That's why they made it.  Forget about Yeoman and Gulp generators.  Start building your app.

Answer (score 8):

First, you should exploit all the potential of express by using its [router](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router), that will allow you to manage easily your routes in separate folders for each subroutine otherwise you can quickly end up with a mess for all the new routines you create.

Serving your client files should be a one-liner by putting them in a specific directory that is easily targetable.

To do something optimised, you'll also have to create a build task that concat and minify all your client files and change their paths in your `index.html`.

---

Old user of the *angular-fullstack* generator and gulp lover, a friend and I came with a new project called **[generator-bangular](https://github.com/42Zavattas/generator-bangular)**. Basically a fullstack generator using **angular**, **gulp** and **express**. It allow you to easily launch a new project with a clean architecture and built-in commands to create everything you need, from a new api route to a directive.

Install it using

```
npm install -g generator-bangular
```

And get started by running

```
yo bangular
```

Comment: thanks for creating the bangular generator. i was looking for something simple with angular, express, and gulp, and your generator was just what i was looking for!

Comment: @harmlessdragon I'm glad you like it! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with this specific problem having so few information about your setup, but i really recommend you to use the [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) for your first MEAN app.

Comment: i have been using angular-fullstack generator for a long time now, but i wanted to start playing with GULP, and i was looking for the same kind of setup but using gulp instead of grunt. i couldnt find anything like that and the closest thing was to use the gulp-angular generator and to manually add to it express and mongo. i almost succeeded but i still have problems with the bower components folder (the index.html can not find them) i think its a problem with the gulp configuration. so i was wondering if anyone managed to setup an  "angular-fullstack generator" like app with gulp ?

Comment: So you should try [mean.io](http://mean.io), when configuring it in the console you can choose between Gulp or Grunt